# issue with property of ForEach is Undefinied in Discord.js (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Index file

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();
const prefix = '!'

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{;
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, discord)
})
client.login(`IREMOVEDTOKENFORTHIS`)
```
(imagine a folder that is named handlers and the stuff below is in it)
```
command_handlers : (below is the file contents)
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`)
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command)
        } else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}
````

event handler

```
const fs = require('fs');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports= (client, Discord)=>{
    const load_dir = (dir) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dir}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dir}/${file}`)
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0]
            client.on(event_name,event.bind(Discord, client));
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

message file (under events folder-->guild)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = (Discord, client, message, args) => {
    const prefix = '!'

    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

    if(command) commands.execute(client, message, args, Discord)
}
```

error

```
['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{;
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\index.js:8:38)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

my bots name is Bombbot and I used to tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sihf7B8D4Y8, which has helped with previous tutorials but this one if a bit confusing and I have rewritten code multiple times. I have also tried removing that whole function but that then makes my code useless.

Comment: Typo, missing comma after `const prefix = '!'`. https://imgur.com/a/YevSTTX

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros semi-colon.

Comment: Yes, my bad, semicolon. I haven't had my coffee yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the issue because of JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) feature.

```
const prefix = '!'

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, discord)
})
```

gets executed as

```
const prefix = '!'['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, discord)
})
```

`'!'['command_handler', 'event_handler']` returns `undefined` and hence the error.

Add a semi-colon at the end of the `prefix` declaration.

```
const prefix = '!';
```

And

```
['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{;
```

should be

```
['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler => {
```